# minicom: cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory

Tags: usb, serial-port

```
[28886.887374] usb 3-2: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[28887.058484] usb 3-2: Detected FT232RL
[28887.066545] usb 3-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[28890.197198] usb 3-2: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ftdi_sio while 'brltty' sets config #1
[30185.049341] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[30194.891274] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[30195.073168] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001, bcdDevice= 6.00
[30195.073175] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[30195.073178] usb 3-2: Product: FT232R USB UART
[30195.073180] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[30195.073181] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: A9HDNHYL
[30195.079271] usb 3-2: Detected FT232RL
[30195.087414] usb 3-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[30195.616247] usb 3-2: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ftdi_sio while 'brltty' sets config #1
[30262.684194] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 5
```

```
:~$ sudo minicom
minicom: cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
```

Comment: remove any packages on your system with `brltty` in name (but only you have no blind family member`